# Why are polynomial multiple regression coefficients missing in poly?

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, polynomials, poly

I ran a polynomial multiple regression in R using `poly`, and in the output the coefficients of some combinations of the two variables (`Unc` and `Window`) are seem to be missing, and I cannot get my head around it.

The input data can be downloaded from [here](http://www.geochem.hu/people/hatvani/mdata3_forum.csv).

The code I used in the following: `per_lm=lm(formula = variable ~ polym(Unc, Window, degree = 4, raw = TRUE), data = mdata3)`

and the output coefficients can be seen in the picture below.

[image: Obtained coefficients]

You can see that combinations such as 2,3; 4,1; 4,2; 4,3; or 1,4 etc. are missing. Does anyone have any idea why can this happen?
I will have to extract the equation of the surface determined by the coefficients to use it in a separate program written by a colleague.

If I consider the "missing" combinations as zero coefficients I cannot reproduce the fitted surface illustrated [here](http://www.geochem.hu/people/hatvani/forum_example.html), where the Period=variable in the input data file attached above. I will have to use the equation of this surface in a separate software that we are writing.
Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: @Roland answered your main question.  For the second part ("I cannot reproduce the fitted surface illustrated below") you'll need to include more information:  what did you try exactly?

Comment: Your linked dataset is different than the one in the figure.  The linked one has 3 points with `Unc == 225` and 6 points with `Unc == 245`.  The plot shows at least 25 points with `Unc` near those values.

Comment: @user2554330 I corrected the figure, I took a wrong prnt scr. I will provide more details soon, thank you!

Comment: You can always add predictors to the formula, e.g., `+ I(Unc ^ 2 * Window ^ 3)` would add the (2, 3) combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows the definition for the degree of a bivariate polynomial consistent with [this equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BivariatePolynomial.html):

[image: formula of a bivariate polynomial]
where n is the degree.

According to this definition 4,1 can only occur in a >= fifth degree polynomial.

Comment: Thanks, but even if this was true, the (2,3) combination is still missing, or zero? But l am quite certain that those coefficients should be there. Please see e.g.   https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=applications
/BivariatePolynomialRegression

or your source, where for a quadratic bivariate case https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultivariatePolynomial.html

Comment: 4-2 = 2, 4-3=1, so no, (2,3) shouldn't be there. The sum of both exponents must equal the degree.